# Can client change JavaScript values their the browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, client

I have a question that I didn't find the answer to, anywhere else.

Can clients change the values of function parameters, variables and ... that are in my scripts?

for example I have a button which calls a JS function which removes a product with the specified ID from the database):

```
<button onclick="deleteProduct(productId: 123);">Delete Product</button>
```

When the clients come to my website, they can open the 'inspect element' tool and change the value of the `productId` parameter of my JS function `deleteProduct` manually; so then they can remove any product by just changing the `productId`.

Is that so? If yes, how can we prevent it?

Comment: Yes. That is why you need client-side verification process (convenience and for non-"hackers") and mandatory server-side verification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. The user is in complete control of everything that happens inside their browser.

If you want to stop people deleting arbitrary things from a database then store the database *on the server* and apply a level of authentication and authorization to any request for a delete query on it.